How to parse a 2 dimensional array of pointers and returns the 2 dimensional array of pointers?
Sorry for disturbing, I am trying to parse a 2D array of pointer like ANIMAL *animal[2][6] into a function and the function will return that 2D array of pointer. It gets error of
[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'ANIMAL*' to 'ANIMAL* [6]'
P.S: just ignore the createNode function, since the error is on line *animal = readFile(animal);
struct ANIMAL {
    char id[10];
    char species[50];
    char type[10];
    char strDate[50];
    time_t create_date = NULL;
    ANIMAL *next;
};

ANIMAL *readFile(ANIMAL *[][6]);
ANIMAL *createNode(ANIMAL *[][6], ANIMAL *, char *, int, int);

int main() {
    ANIMAL *animal[2][6];
    
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            animal[j][i] = (ANIMAL *)malloc(sizeof(ANIMAL));
            animal[j][i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    *animal = readFile(animal);
}

ANIMAL *readFile(ANIMAL *animal[][6]) {
    FILE *file;
    ANIMAL *temp[1];
    char data[180], date[20];
    int i;
    
    file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        while (fgets(data, sizeof(ANIMAL), file)) {
            temp[0] = (ANIMAL *)malloc(sizeof(ANIMAL));
            char *token = strtok(data, "|");
            strcpy(temp[0]->id, token);
            
            token = strtok(NULL, "|");
            strcpy(temp[0]->species, token);
            
            token = strtok(NULL, "|");
            strcpy(temp[0]->type, token);
            if (strcmp(temp[0]->type, "mamal") == 0)     i = 0;
            if (strcmp(temp[0]->type, "bird") == 0)      i = 1;
            if (strcmp(temp[0]->type, "reptile") == 0)   i = 2;
            if (strcmp(temp[0]->type, "amphibian") == 0) i = 3;
            if (strcmp(temp[0]->type, "insect") == 0)    i = 4;
            if (strcmp(temp[0]->type, "unknown") == 0)   i = 5;
            token = strtok(NULL, "|");
            strcpy(temp[0]->strDate, token);
            
            token = strtok(NULL, "|");
            strcpy(date, token);

            temp[0]->create_date = atoi(date);
            token = strtok(NULL, "|");
            
            *animal = createNode(animal, temp[0], temp[0]->type, i, 2);
        }   
    } else {
        printf("No data found\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
    return *animal;
}

ANIMAL *createNode(ANIMAL *animal[], ANIMAL *temp, char *type, int i, int condition) {
    char buff[20], id[10], species[50];
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    ANIMAL *newNode;
    
    newNode = (ANIMAL *)malloc(sizeof(ANIMAL));
    if (condition == 2) {
        newNode = temp;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if (animal[i] != NULL) {
            newNode->next = animal[i];
        }
        animal[i] = newNode;
        //printf("/t%d",i);
        return *animal;
    }
    
    newNode->create_date = now;
    strftime(buff, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));
    strcpy(newNode->strDate, buff);

    insert_id:
    printf("\nEnter Animal ID: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &id);
    if (!validation(animal, id)) {
        goto insert_id;
    }
    strcpy(newNode->id, id);

    printf("Enter Animal Species: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", &species);
    strcpy(newNode->species, species);
    strcpy(newNode->type, type);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (animal[i] != NULL) {
        newNode->next = animal[i];
    }
    
    animal[i] = newNode;
    return *animal;
}

before this, im using 1D array and it works. After changing into 2D array it has error. I wonder what are the mistake(s) that I've done and how to parse and return 2D pointer array.

animal[j][i] = (ANIMAL*)malloc(sizeof(ANIMAL)); animal[j][i] = NULL; initializes the pointer to NULL and creates a memory leak.

Are you sure that you are using C? There is a lot of stuff in the code that only works in C++:  time_t create_date = NULL; in the struct definition, every ANIMAL should be struct ANIMAL, ...

@mch im sorry about it, im new to C, can i know the difference of C and C++?

*animal = readFile(animal); doesn't make any sense -- what are you trying to do?  Basically, it you compile your code it gives you perfectly sensible errors about the type mismatches.  Fix those, and you might have a question.

@ChrisDodd actually I'm gonna to use the 2D array to store pointer of linked list for different languages. For example: animal[0][] will be english, animal[1][] will be in malay. My idea was to parse 2D array into readFile() to create linked list in that 2D array, then return the 2D array

arrays and linked lists are two totally different data structures, so "create linked list in that 2D array" makes no sense.  You also can't return arrays in C -- only pointers to arrays.  Your readFile function is returning a pointer to an ANIMAL -- which might be either a pointer into an array, or the head of a linked list.

More specific to your code -- it seems like you're passing a pointer to an array to readFile as an argument, so it can fill that in and there's no need to return anything (other than a success/fail code)

There is no reason to use a 2D array of pointers to ANIMAL structures. The second dimension seems to correspond to the animal type, but the use of the first dimension is unclear and probably not needed.
Also fgets(data, sizeof(ANIMAL), file) is incorrect, you should pass the size of the data character array instead of the size of the ANIMAL structure.
The main function should just initialize the array elements to NULL, which can be done simply with an initializer.
There is no need for readFile to return the array pointer, make it return a success/failure indicator.
Here is a modified version:
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ANIMAL {
    char id[10];
    char species[50];
    char type[10];
    char strDate[50];
    time_t create_date;
    ANIMAL *next;
} ANIMAL;

bool readFile(ANIMAL animals[6]);

ANIMAL *createNode(ANIMAL *[][6], ANIMAL *, char *, int, int);

int main(void) {
    ANIMAL *animal[6] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL };

    if (!readFile(animal)) {
       fprintf(stderr, "cannot read animal file\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

const char * const animal_types[5] = { "mamal", "bird", "reptile", "amphibian", "insect" };

int get_animal_type(const char *type) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strcmp(type, animal_types[i]) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 5;  /* unknown */
}

bool readFile(ANIMAL animal[6]) {
    char data[180], date[20];
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", "data.txt", strerror(errno));
        return false;
    }

    while (fgets(data, sizeof(data), file)) {
        ANIMAL *temp = (ANIMAL *)malloc(sizeof(*temp));
        if (temp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failure\n");
            break;
        }
        char *token = strtok(data, "|");
        if (!token)
            break;
        strcpy(temp->id, token);
        
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
        if (!token)
            break;
        strcpy(temp->species, token);
        
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
        if (!token)
            break;
        strcpy(temp->type, token);
        int i = get_animal_type(temp->type);

        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
        if (!token)
            break;
        strcpy(temp->strDate, token);
        
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
        if (!token)
            break;
        strcpy(date, token);

        temp->create_date = atoi(date);

        createNode(animal, temp, temp->type, i, 2);
    } 
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

ANIMAL *createNode(ANIMAL *animal[], ANIMAL *temp, char *type, int i, int condition) {
    char buff[20], id[10], species[50], type[10];
    
    if (condition == 2) {
        temp->next = animal[i];
        animal[i] = temp;
        return temp;
    }
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    ANIMAL *newNode = (ANIMAL *)malloc(sizeof(ANIMAL));
    newNode->create_date = now;
    strftime(newNode->strDate, sizeof newNode->strDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));

    for (;;) {
        printf("\nEnter Animal ID: ");
        scanf(" %9[^\n]", id);
        if (validation(animal, id))
            break;
    }
    strcpy(newNode->id, id);
    printf("Enter Animal Species: ");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]", species);
    strcpy(newNode->species, species);
    printf("Enter Animal Type: ");
    scanf(" %9[^\n]", type);
    strcpy(newNode->type, type);
    i = get_animal_type(type);
    newNode->next = animal[i];
    animal[i] = newNode;
    return newNode;
}


@cwz: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.
